# Cannot read property 'textContent' of null at renderTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

I'm trying to create a working clock with JavaScript, but the code won't run. I'm getting the following error in my console:

> Cannot read property 'textContent' of null at renderTime

This is the HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/alarm.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>Alarm Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clockDisplay" class="clockStyle">3 : 15 : 25 AM</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
function renderTime() {

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var diem = "AM";
  var h = currentTime.getHours();
  var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  } else if (h < 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    diem = "PM"
  }

  if (h < 10) {
    h = "0" + h;
  }

  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }

  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }



  var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
  myClock.textContent(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "" + diem);
  setTimeout('renderTime()', 1000)

}

renderTime();
```

Comment: Include the script at the end of the body tag or wait till the DOM is loaded

Comment: You're going to want to play with (reduce) the timeout delay a bit, or you will get odd "seconds" display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the script is executing before the page is loaded.

You just need to move the `js/alarm.js` script tag to the end of your body tag, so it executes when the page is fully loaded.

And `textContent` is a property and not a `function` so your code will raise an Exception, change the following line:

```
myClock.textContent ( h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "" + diem);
```

To:

```
myClock.textContent =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "" + diem;
```

**Demo:**

I refactored your code and corrected it so it takes in consideration these changes, this is a working snippet:

```js
function renderTime(){

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var diem = "AM";
  var h = currentTime.getHours();
  var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  } else if (h < 12) {
    h = h-12;
    diem = "PM"
  }

  if (h < 10) {
    h = "0" + h;
  }

  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }

  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }



   var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
    myClock.textContent =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "" + diem;
      setTimeout('renderTime()', 1000)

  }

  renderTime();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Alarm Clock</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="clockDisplay" class="clockStyle">3 : 15 : 25 AM</div>
    <script src="js/alarm.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you @chsdk both suggested solutions have worked

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is the fact that the function is called when the browser parses the script tag. By then the actual HTML body has not been parsed/rendered and the element is indeed not found in the dom.

Try:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/alarm.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Alarm Clock</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="renderTime();">
     <div id="clockDisplay" class="clockStyle">3 : 15 : 25 AM</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And remove the function call at then end of your script.